# Event to remove search dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It might be pretty obvious for most of the developers but I am not able to figure out when to remove the search dropdown created as a part of Key press event.

This is my current script and I am adding the dropdown named `searchDropDown` to the existing div which have the text input as well. So the only problem is when to remove the `searchDropdown` box? Because if I remove on blur of text input it will remove the dropdown before anything selected.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq2Xc/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    //First handler to focus & blur
    $("div.searchBox input[type=text]").focus(function() {      
        if($(this).val() == "Enter location"){
            $(this).val("");
        }else{
        }
        $(this).css("color", "black");
    });
    $("div.searchBox").focusin(function() {
        console.debug("focus");
    });
    $("div.searchBox").focusout(function() {
        console.debug("focusout");
        return;
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).val("Enter location");
        }           
        $("div#searchDropDown").remove();       
        $(this).css("color", "gray");               
    }); 

    //Keydown create dropdown
    $("div.searchBox input[type=text]").keyup(function() {      
//      console.debug($("div.searchBox input[type=text]").val());
        if($("div.searchBox input[type=text]").val().length > 3){
            $("div#searchDropDown").remove();
            //send ajax request.            
            createDropDownDiv("Jaipur,delhi");
        }else{
            //remove Dropdown
            $("div#searchDropDown").remove();
        }
    });
});

function createDropDownDiv(searchListStr){
    var divString;
    divString = "<div id='searchDropDown'>";
    var searchList = searchListStr.split(",");

    for ( var int = 0; int < searchList.length; int++) {
        divString += "<p class='searchResultItem'>";
        divString += searchList[int];
        divString += "</p>";
    }

    divString += "</div>";
    $("div.searchBox").append(divString);
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Fiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/gq2Xc/

Comment: You have to hide onclick event in "searchResultItem" in result

Comment: @Jak But that will be issue because the drop down should also hide if the focus moves out of the searchBox div

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your current code

```
 $(document).on("click",".searchResultItem",function(){
$("div.searchBox input[type=text]").val($(this).html());
    $(".searchResultItem").remove();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gq2Xc/2/)

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gq2Xc/5/)

Comment: But it would not hide even if my searchbox doesn't have the focus i.e. it should hide when the searchbox is no longer in focus.

Comment: Thanks Anup, but you see, now the value is not getting loaded in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it in the onBlur event

```
$("div.searchBox input[type=text]").blur(function() {
    //remove Dropdown
    $("div#searchDropDown").remove();
});
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gq2Xc/3/)**

Comment: No, it would create issue coz I can't select anything from dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("div.searchBox").on('focusout', function() {
```

instead of

```
$("div.searchBox").focusout(function() {
```

because it's a dynamically created element. [jQuery 'on'](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

And why you are `return`ing before removing the element?

```
$("div.searchBox").on('focusout', function() {
        console.debug("focusout");
        //return
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).val("Enter location");
        }           
        $("div#searchDropDown").remove();       
        $(this).css("color", "gray");               
        return; // return here
    });
```

<kbd>[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZws7/)</kbd>

Comment: Alex, you see, I am not able to get the selected value now in this case.